# How to determine if my data is discrete or continuous in java?

Tags: continuous-data, discrete-data, java

Could you mind to teach me how can I test whether the given data is discrete or continuous in java?

For example, given array (98.6, 99.2, 103.1) and my statistic service should determine the data type.

Comment: I have a human brain, and I cannot determine whether your example data is discrete or continuous.

Comment: The specified array just an example please don't concentrate on that data, actually data comes from database and I have no idea which kind of data is it. I just want to know are there any algorithm by which I can determine the data type?